# MaxDate and MinDate Datetimepicker from TextBox Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetimepicker

In Java Script

```
    $(function () {

        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
        });

        var c = new Date(document.getElementById("<%=lblDateIn.ClientID%>").value);
        var d = new Date(document.getElementById("<%=lblDateIn.ClientID%>").value);
        c.setDate(c.getDate());
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        $('#datepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
            minDate: c,
            maxDate: d,
        });
    });
```

The MaxDate Value Change MinDate Value after show popup Modal

Comment: Try to explain your case with more and clear info.

Comment: MinDate and MaxDate from one TextBox, but after show modal pop up, if i choose MaxDate Value, the value change MinDate

Comment: your question is still unclear

Comment: example: MinDate 22-2-2017, MaxDate 23-2-2017, when I choose MaxDate = 23-2-2016 in TextBox, the value back MinDate = 22-2-2017 if show modal pop up